# How to differentiate between polygon resizing and polygon position change in open layers

Tags: javascript, angular, openlayers

These are the values of the polygon in the old state when its resized.

```
((16.077870046431798 81.6098376362265,18.779390417804365 80.59782000622528,14.530980964163305 80.33180518275631,12.604678172608644 81.82484824254053,13.578507736770405 83.43529780626201,16.077870046431798 81.6098376362265)).

These are the values of the polygon in the new state when its resized. ((16.077870046431926 81.60983763622635,15.20466061176657 79.3137892053278,14.530980964163433 80.33180518275616,12.604678172608772 81.82484824254038,13.578507736770547 83.43529780626187,16.077870046431926 81.60983763622635))

These are the values when the polygon is moved from one place to another.
old value: ((12.194042017373988 80.59537032875853,14.946516853751504 79.5833526987573,10.621961817356663 79.31733787528833,8.668366948574786 80.81038093507256,9.655427554249343 82.42083049879405,12.194042017373988 80.59537032875853))

new value: ((16.077870046431798 81.6098376362265,18.779390417804365 80.59782000622528,14.530980964163305 80.33180518275631,12.604678172608644 81.82484824254053,13.578507736770405 83.43529780626201,16.077870046431798 81.6098376362265))
```

If i have to pop a error message for position change and a backend api call for the resize. How do i differentiate?

```
Tried comparing coordinates only slight diff observed.
```

Comment: Calculate the geometry extent width, height and center and check for differences greater than a tolerance such as 1e-10 or whatever is suitable for your application.  If width or height has changed the geometry has been resized, if only the center has changed it has been moved.